# reference an object within an array of objects in Angular 2 inside of template

Tags: angular

Maybe this is a stupid question. After reading several times this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html I can not find a solution, to reference an object within an array of objects.

I tried it with this

```
{{ users[0] ? users[0].description }}
```

I obtain this

> Parser Error: Conditional expression {{ users[0] ?
>   users[0].description }}  requires all 3 expressions at the end of the
>   expression [ {{ users[0] ? users[0].description }} ] in

---

I tried it with this

```
{{ users.0 ? users.0.description }}
```

I obtain this

> Unexpected token '0' at column 7 in [ {{ users.0 ? users.0.description
>   }} ]

---

any of the above syntax is correct and my mistake is elsewhere, or none of the above is correct. Sorry for my English

somewhere in code

```
..//
  users: Array<Object>;
  ..//
  this.users = new Array();
  ..//
  this.users.push(users.json())
  ..//
```

Comment: Have you tried it like this `{{ users[0] ? users[0].description : '' }}`?

Comment: @DonovanM I think it was my mistake because I had parts where used,{{ users[0] ? users[0].description: null}}, but it looks that I forget some, if you want to post a reply? Thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, just added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the "else" part of the ternary operator. So just change it to:

`{{ users[0] ? users[0].description : '' }}`

Answer (score 2):

You were probably looking for

```
{{ users[0]?.description }}
```